# Filling in missing dates Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Account   Value   Last_Day_in_Month

ABC       7        2018-06-30
ABC      12        2018-06-30
ABC       3        2018-08-31
FGH      57        2019-01-31
FGH      13        2019-03-31
FGH       127      2019-03-31
```

For each account, I need to fill in the missing dates corresponding to the last day in each month such that the resulting table just fills in the value from the last month (you'll notice two additional rows)

```
Account   Value   Last_Day_in_Month

ABC       7        2018-06-30
ABC      12        2018-06-30
ABC      12        2018-07-31
ABC       3        2018-08-31
FGH      57        2019-01-31
FGH      57        2019-02-28
FGH      13        2019-03-31
FGH       127      2019-03-31
```

I have many accounts each of them with different start and stop times (Last_Day_in_Month) so I only need to fill in the missing months between the min and max months for each account. Because I may have multiple values corresponding to one single month end date per account, my current solution is to use a lead with a case statement that adds a single day and a date table that contains only the last day of each month and perform a cross join. But, I think it's messy and I'm sure there's a better way that I'm not aware of. Here is my current solution...

```
select
        *,
        lead(Last_Day_in_Month,1)over (
            partition by Account
            order by Last_Day_in_Month
        ) as intermed2,

        case 
            when intermed2 = Last_Day_in_Month
            then dateadd('day',1, intermed2)

            else intermed2

        end as next_last_day

    from table
    cross join dates 
        where dates.date_actual >= table.Last_Day_in_Month
            and dates.date_actual < table.next_last_day
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is fine for reasonable numbers of rows.  One thing I'd recommend for clarity is changing from a cross join to a right join with an ON clause.  The query planner should see right through what you have and plan an efficient query so just a nit.

There are a number of other ways to do this and you can find examples by searching "gaps and islands" in stack overflow.  The biggest feedback I have is about creating additional rows.  What you are doing is making new rows for the missing months which is fine for reasonably small tables because they don't get super large when you add rows.  For example if you have a table with 100 billion rows and you have an average gap size of 2, you will be creating a result with 300 billion rows.  Making this much data will never be fast or efficient. So you say you have "many accounts", how many is many?

If the amount of data can fit in memory or you are doing this operation only once in a while then creating rows will work ok.  If this is being done as part of ongoing queries and the data created will be large then I'd rethink why you need to create data to get your queries to execute.  In general Redshift stores very large sets of data and multiplying out (cross join) these rows by some other factor (dates) will result in very slow queries.  If the the intent is to pared this data down to some smaller result you will want to find a way to create this result without making such a large intermediate dataset.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. As far as number of accounts... we operate in the 10s of thousands range and as far as time series probably 10M or less rows. Can you elaborate a bit on why a right join with an ON clause would be better? I see a right join introducing many dates that are not applicable to some accounts. I should have said earlier but each account has a subscription start and end date so it would not make sense to right join a dates table because each account would end up retaining all dates in the dates table, even those outside of start and end date which I definitely do not want.

Comment: 10M rows is likely ok for using the JOIN method if the number of gap dates is less than 10 on average.  Creating large amounts of data can get expensive. You caught me without enough coffee - I misread the SQL, should be <table> LEFT JOIN <dates> with an ON clause with the inequality condition.  This is primarily a readability concern - what your query says is join every row in table with every row in date then remove the one that don't meet the WHERE clause.  The query optimizer will realize this is actually a JOIN ON and rewrite the query.  As I said this is a nit.